# How to increase font size in swi prolog HELP app?

Tags: swi-prolog

How to increase font size in swi-prolog HELP app ?

?- help.

the font is really small and hard to read

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the swish, then you can increase the Zoom in your browser (Google Chrome). Or you can pinch out your touch pad on your laptop to Zoom in.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: linux, swipl shell